# Who were the gods depicted in Star Trek V?

Tags: star-trek

Near the end of *Star Trek V: The Final Frontier*, McCoy asked the entity "Is this the voice of God?"  The entity responded "One voice, many faces," and a series of faces appeared onscreen, presumably depicting deities out of human history or mythology.  The faces seemed vaguely familiar, but I couldn't identify them.  Assuming these faces were taken from real source material, who were these gods?

Screenshots of the gods:
[image: god 1]
[image: god 2]
[image: god 3]
[image: god 4]
[image: god 5]

Comment: You know that mythological deities don't have canonical faces, right?  That's why artists usually have to identify them with symbolic artifacts or creatures.

Comment: Yes, hence the mention of source material.  If the images above match masks recovered from archaelogical digs, cave paintings, architectural friezes, etc. then any of those would be an acceptable basis for an answer.

Comment: I'm tempted to downvote just for bringing up such a horrible movie and inflicting any portion of it upon the general population of the Earth.  :)  But it is an interesting question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**From the Star Trek Wikia entree on [Sha Ka Ree](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/God_%28Sha_Ka_Ree%29):**

The Human image portrayed by the "God of Sha Ka Ree" from Star Trek V was portrayed by actor George Murdock. The image of the Andorian God, as well as the other two unidentified Gods (shown), were among the images proposed to represent the "many faces of God" in Star Trek V. These images, however, did not make it into the final production of the movie, but were included in the Special Features section of the [Star Trek V: The Final Frontier (Special Edition) DVD](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek_V:_The_Final_Frontier_%28Special_Edition%29).

[image]

Comment: Very interesting!  The last two are close matches to the first and fourth screen images.  I was quite surprised to see those ram horns; I wonder what the thinking was behind removing them.

Comment: I am disturbed by the use of `"` in this image.

Comment: @Raphael: Why exactly?

Comment: @Bobby: They suggest that one of the depicted gods is more real than the others.

Comment: @Raphael: Oh that, yes, I also noticed that after commenting...it's the inconsistent use.

Comment: Accepted.  I'm satisfied that the other faces were likely similar _ad hoc_ creations for the film.

Comment: @Raphael - What! You do not believe that the god of Andoria is the one true god, and all others are but imposters?